# Swift - Problems with Programmatically Positioning UIButton (Universal)

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, sprite-kit, swift2

I am trying to convert an app that I have made from "iPhone" to "Universal", I have successfully sized and positioned everything except the UIButtons I have made. Every time I test the app the UIButtons are positioned perfectly on all iPhones, but when I run and test it on iPad devices the UIButtons are always positioned differently(examples include: My buttons becoming elongated, overlapping, repositioned etc.,)
The code below has me given my the best results:

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit
import GameKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {

var PlayButton : UIButton!
var GameCenterButton : UIButton!

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    PlayButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: view.frame.size.width / 3, height: 60))
    PlayButton.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2 - 70, y: view.frame.size.height / 1.275)
    PlayButton.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    PlayButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    PlayButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("plyGame"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view?.addSubview(PlayButton)
    let PlayButtonImage = UIImage(named: "RBI") as UIImage!
    _  = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
    PlayButton.setImage(PlayButtonImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    GameCenterButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: view.frame.size.width / 3, height: 60))
    GameCenterButton.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2 + 70, y: view.frame.size.height / 1.275)
    GameCenterButton.setTitle("gc", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    GameCenterButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    GameCenterButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("Ldboards"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view?.addSubview(GameCenterButton)
    let GameCenterButtonImage = UIImage(named: "GCI") as UIImage!
    _  = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
    GameCenterButton.setImage(GameCenterButtonImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Side Note: I am using Xcode 7.1 and the Swift 2.0 Syntax

Comment: did you find a solution that works besides setting constraints?  have you tried using pdfs with the "universal" instead of "ipad" and "iphone"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to use auto layout  in this case and try to give constraint to button  . for example if you want to give button width which is 0.33 of the screen width then give constraint like this

```
    let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: button.superview, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 0.33, constant: 0)
```

self.view.addConstraint(constraint)

Comment: Actually it didn't work after all, it was an issue on the simulator. I was prompted with this message " (Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.) " Is there any other way this could be done?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with something similar but I'm not sure if my solution will apply to your situation. Depending on how your scene is embedded in the rest of the app, the solution may be different.

I have my SKView inside a view container which is part of a mix of regular UIViews and controls.  My call to skView.presentScene() is in the controller's viewWillAppear() method.

What I discovered is that didMoveToView is sometimes called before the auto-layout is finished laying out its subviews.  This sometimes provides the SKView with the wrong (design time) bounds.

To work around the problem, I moved the initialization code that depended on view size to a separate function which I call (only once) from the controller's viewDidLayoutSubviews() method.

Hope this helps